# How can I find end point using start point, angle and distance

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have following metrics

```
Vec2 start = Vec2(20, 20);
float angle = 64.0f;
float distance = 500.0f;
```

And I want to find end point but i couldn't figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can I find end point using start point, angle and distance?

```
Vec2 start     = Vec2(20, 20);
float angle    = 64.0f;
float distance = 500.0f;
```

To prepare for the operation, you have to include

```
#include <math.h>
```

First you have to transform the `angle` from [Degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)) to [Radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), because for the following functions the angle is required in radians:

```
float angle_rad = angle * 3.1415927f / 180.0f;
```

Then you have to calcualte the direction [Unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector).
This can be done by the [Trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) Consine (`cos`) and [Sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) (`sin`):

```
Vec2 dir_vec(cos(angle_rad), sin(angle_rad));
```

The `end` point is the `start` point plus the the direction unit vector (`dir_vec`) multiplied by the `distance`:

```
Vec2 end = start + distance * dir_vec;
```